# Is this correct? "...the user has either finished dragging or dragged out of the upload modal an item"

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas, parallelism, coordinating-conjunctions

> Creates an action to indicate that the user has either finished dragging or dragged out of the upload modal an item.

My intent is for "an item" to serve as object for both 'dragging' and 'dragged.' Is this sentence grammatical, or does it require some commas?

Comment: It's unclear because it is too compressed. Also, 'an item' is an object. Maybe you could use this: "the user has either finished dragging an item, or at least dragged it out of the upload modal."

Comment: Thanks for catching my subject/object slip-up. I've corrected my question.

Answer (score 0):

> Creates an action to indicate that the user has either finished
>   dragging or has dragged an item out of the upload modal.

As a minor point, the finished dragging and has dragged are both past tense of 'to drag' and mean the same thing. If you have finished dragging something, you have dragged it.

If you meant to use a present and past tense, you could use this:

> Creates an action to indicate that the user is either dragging or has
>   dragged an item out of the upload modal.

In each case, the use of 'an item' would immediately follow the second option rather than be placed at the end of the sentence.

Comment: I should clarify the meaning of the original sentence. There are two cases: (1) the user has finished dragging an item; or (2) the user is still dragging an item, but has dragged it out of the upload modal. The 'action' indicates that one of these two cases holds.

Comment: So, in either case, it has been dragged out of the upload modal. Regardless of whether it has been dragged to its desired destination or not. So why not say *Creates an action to indicate that the user has dragged an item out of the upload modal.* and be done?

Comment: In case (1), the user may _not_ have dragged the item out of the upload modal--she may have finished dragging the item while still inside the upload modal.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. In either case the use of 'an item', grammatically speaking, should immediately follow the final condition in the 'or' statement.

> This or that elephant.
> This, that or the other elephant.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment on the first answer:

> Creates an action to indicate that the user has either **dragged an item out of the upload modal** or **finished dragging altogether**.

The in-process state ("dragged an item out of the upload model") goes before the finished state ("finished dragging ***altogether***").

The '*altogether*' is important here. This is to indicate "dragging" consists of more steps than just "dragging an item out of upload model".

---

### EDIT

You need to show that dragging an item can be done two (or more) ways. It's not very clear by your sentence. You say, an item need not be dragged out of the upload model to drag it completely out (of the entire system you're involved in). It can be dragged out altogether by other means, too.

This is what I inferred from your comments. I might be very much wrong. The whole subject matter is extremely confusing to me.

As it currently stands, your sentence is very ambiguous. And without further context or background, it'll be hard for us here to help you clarify the sentence.